Significant Differences in BusyBox Binaries Despite Using Same Configuration on Tinycore Linux
I successfully built BusyBox in Tinycore Linux version 11.x, following the instructions from Tinycore's BusyBox compilation guide, although the guide is for version 14.x.
Issue Description:
I'm currently using the BusyBox included in corepure64.gz from Tinycore 14.0. My goal is to compile a BusyBox version that closely matches the one in corepure64.gz, using the same nosuid.config as suggested in the compile guide.
Problem Encountered:
I compiled two versions of BusyBox, named obusybox1 and obusybox5. To identify differences, I used hexdump and diff as follows:
$ hexdump -C obusybox1 > obusybox1.hex
$ hexdump -C obusybox5 > obusybox5.hex
$ diff -u obusybox1.hex obusybox5.hex
--- obusybox1.hex    2024-08-03 07:40:28.257532542 +0900
+++ obusybox5.hex    2024-08-03 07:40:37.221691421 +0900
@@ -30673,7 +30673,7 @@
 000791c0  25 73 27 00 6f 75 74 20  6f 66 20 6d 65 6d 6f 72  |%s'.out of memor|
 000791d0  79 00 42 75 73 79 42 6f  78 20 76 31 2e 33 36 2e  |y.BusyBox v1.36.|
 000791e0  30 20 28 32 30 32 34 2d  30 38 2d 30 31 20 31 37  |0 (2024-08-01 17|
-000791f0  3a 30 36 3a 30 37 20 55  54 43 29 00 2f 64 65 76  |:06:07 UTC)./dev|
+000791f0  3a 33 30 3a 35 30 20 55  54 43 29 00 2f 64 65 76  |:30:50 UTC)./dev|
 00079200  2f 74 74 79 00 4c 49 4e  45 53 00 43 4f 4c 55 4d  |/tty.LINES.COLUM|
 00079210  4e 53 00 64 75 6d 62 00  63 61 6e 27 74 20 6f 70  |NS.dumb.can't op|
 00079220  65 6e 20 27 25 73 27 00  63 61 6e 27 74 20 72 65  |en '%s'.can't re|

The differences are due to build time strings, which is acceptable. However, comparing obusybox1 with the BusyBox in corepure64.gz shows significant differences:
$ diff -u obusybox1.hex busybox.hex | diffstat
busybox.hex |68071 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 file changed, 34023 insertions(+), 34048 deletions(-)

Question:
Why is there such a significant difference between obusybox1 and the BusyBox in corepure64.gz, despite using the same configuration file?
